# How to remove newLines at the beginning and at the end of a Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string, replace, trim

I need to remove newlines at the beginning and at the end of a string in ruby (some sort of trimming).

But JUST at the beginning and the end... The new lines located in the middle of the string must remain untouched.

Thank you!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-strip) method.

```
"\tgoodbye\r\n".strip   #=> "goodbye"
```

Comment: If you end up using `strip!` to modify the variable "in-place" then watch out, because it returns `nil` when it doesn't have to strip anything from the beginning or the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

String.strip will remove all extra whitespace from the front and back, leaving innards alone.

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001189

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
string.lstrip!.rstrip!
```

Comment: I think as well lstrip + rstrip == strip, but that should be confirmed first.

Comment: @Felix Can confirm `"\n\r\sfoo\s\r\n".lstrip.rstrip.eql? "\n\r\sfoo\s\r\n".strip` returns `true`.

Comment: @ennuikiller: Could you update the answer (and include link to doc)?

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to strip just whitespace then the strip method should work...but if your trying to target new lines specifically then maybe try this:

```
"\r\na b c d\r\ne f g\r\n".gsub(/^\r\n/, "").gsub(/\r\n$/, "")
=> "a b c d\r\ne f g"
```

the gsub method will use regular expression to target the beginning ^ and end $ locations for replacement with "".

NOTE: Here I made the assumption that your newline is \r\n. This may not be platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

The platform independent version of [NPatel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167178/how-to-remove-newlines-at-the-beginning-and-at-the-end-of-a-ruby-string/7173618#7173618) is:

```
"\nabc\ndef\n".gsub(/^#{$/}/, "").gsub(/#{$/}$/, "")
```